# How to convert this timer into 60 minutes?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, countdown

I am facing a problem when convert this timer in 60 minutes, now the timer is of 5 minutes, so how to convert it into 60 minutes?

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes,
    seconds;
    
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + " " + " " + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
    
    console.log(parseInt(seconds))
    window.localStorage.setItem("seconds", seconds)
    window.localStorage.setItem("minutes", minutes)
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  sec = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("seconds"))
  min = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("minutes"))

  if (parseInt(min * sec)) {
    var fiveMinutes = (parseInt(min * 60) + sec);
  }
  else {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5;
  }
  
  // var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5;
  display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Just replace `var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5` with `var fiveMinutes = 60 * 60`

Answer (score 0):

You could rename `fiveMinutes` to `time` and set it to 60 * 60 for a one hour countdown.

```
if (parseInt(min * sec)) {
    var time = (parseInt(min * 60) + sec);
  }
  else {
    var time = 60 * 60;
  }
  
  // var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5;
  display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(time, display);
```

Comment: @sushantkumbhar No problem.

Comment: Would you mind [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Sushant!

To make the default duration of the timer 60 minutes, replace "60 * 5" (which calculates the number of seconds in 5 minutes) with "60 * 60" (which calculates the number of seconds in 60 minutes, or 1 hour).

You should also replace occurrences of "fiveMinutes" with "duration" or "seconds" because the variable represents a duration in seconds.